# Gwibber-service keeps running after uninstall

Tags: gwibber

I uninstalled Gwibber a couple weeks ago. However the gwibber service keeps starting every once in a while. Is there any way to prevent this?

Answer (score 3):

Uninstall the package `gwibber-service` and log in again.